# How to display paragraphs coming from a single element in Angular with the required characters working

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a object in view.component.ts file coming form backend. It is supposed to be description for a product. It has more than 500 lines of text. for eg:

```
{"description" : "Hello my Name is Param Bedi.\r\nHow are you\r\n\r...continue till 500 lines and more"}
```

I need to display this to Angular view. But its just coming straight as it is ie containing all the "\r\n" etc. Its not inserting a new line instead of \n.

This is what I am doing in view.component.html

```html
<div>
  <p>{{ data["description"] }}</p>
</div>
```

What should I do so that I can display the data with newline and other special characters working?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [HTMLElement.innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText):

```html
<div>
  <p [innerText]="data.description"></p>
</div>
```

Or, if you need special character output, using [Element.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) (with replacing new lines with `<br>`):

```html
<div>
  <p [innerHTML]="data.description.replace(/(\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br>')"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: It actually worked and inserted newLines and other characters. But some characters are still coming. Foreg &#x2022;

Comment: I found that instead of [innerText], if I use [innerHTML], special characters like &#x2022; are coming as bullet. But this results in newline characters not working.

Comment: @ParamBedi check out updated answer using `innerHTML`

Comment: Yup. This solution worked! Thank you so much for your effort. I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: You can use  **white-space: pre-line** in css. You can check here [CSS White Space](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp).

Solution 2: You can use **Textarea** with **readonly**.

```html
<textarea name="description" readonly [(ngModel)]="data.descrption" style="resize: none;" ></textarea>
```

Comment: This works but there are some characters still coming like &#x2022;